# PHP - Arrays and Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I searched in Google and consulted the PHP documentation, but couldn't figure out how the following code works:

```
$some='name=Licensing Module;nextduedate=2013-04-10;status=Active|name=Test Addon;nextduedate=2013-04-11;status=Active';
function getActiveAddons($somet) {
    $addons = array( );
    foreach ($somet as $addon) {

        if ($addon['status'] == 'Active') {
            $addons[] = $addon['name'];
            continue;
        }
    }

    return $addons;
}
echo (count( getActiveAddons( $some ) ) ? implode( '<br />', getActiveAddons( $some ) ) : 'None');
```

The code always echo's `None`.

Please help me in this.

Comment: Try `var_dump($addon)` - does it look like what you think it should?

Comment: What would you expect? Your argument is a string, not an array: `foreach` will be skipped.

Comment: @str actually foreach can work with any object that implements the Traversable interface. But your point is still valid :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you got this code from but you've initialized `$some` the wrong way. It is expected as an array like this:

```
$some = array(
    array(
     'name' => 'Licensing Module',
     'nextduedate' => '2013-04-10',
     'status' => 'Active'
    ),
    array(
     'name' => 'Test Addon'
     'nextduedate' => '2013-04-11',
     'status' => 'Active'
    )
 );
```

I guess the article you've read is expecting you to parse the original string into this format.

You can achieve this like this:

```
$string = 'name=Licensing Module;nextduedate=2013-04-10;status=Active|name=Test Addon;nextduedate=2013-04-11;status=Active';

$result = array();
foreach(explode('|', $string) as $record) {
    $item = array();
    foreach(explode(';', $record) as $column) {
        $keyval = explode('=', $column);
        $item[$keyval[0]] = $keyval[1];
    }
    $result[]= $item;
}

// now call your function
getActiveAddons($result);
```

Comment: Alright, thank you. Can you change the code so that it works with the $some input that is defined? Thank you very much :D

Comment: Give me a minute. Will prepare

Answer (score 0):

$some is not an array so foreach will not operate on it.  You need to do something like

```
$some = array(
   array(
      'name' => 'Licensing Module',
      'nextduedate' => '2013-04-10',
      'status' => 'Active'
   ),
   array(
      'name' => 'Test Addon',
      'nextduedate' => '2013-04-11',
      'status'=> 'Active'
   )
);
```

This will create a multidimensional array that you can loop through.

```
function getActiveAddons($somet) {
    $addons = array( );
    foreach ($somet as $addon) {
        foreach($addon as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 'status' && $value == 'Active') {
                $addons[] = $addon['name'];
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return $addons;
}
```

Comment: Alright, thank you. Can you change the code so that it works with the $some input that is defined? Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

First, your $some variable is just a string.  You could parse the string into an array using explode(), but it's easier to just start as an array:

```
$some = array(
    array(
        "name" => "Licensing Module",
        "nextduedate" => "2013-04-10",
        "status" => "Active",
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Test Addon",
        "nextduedate" => "2013-04-11",
        "status" => "Active",
    )
);
```

Now, for your function, you are on the right track, but I'll just clean it up:

```
function getActiveAddons($somet) {
    if (!is_array($somet)) {
        return false;
    }

    $addons = array();
    foreach ($somet as $addon) {
        if ($addon['status'] == 'Active') {
            $addons[] = $addon['name'];
        }
    }

    if (count($addons) > 0) {
        return $addons;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And finally your output (you were calling the function twice):

```
$result = getActiveAddons($some);

if ($result === false) {
    echo "No active addons!";
}
else {
    echo implode("<br />", $result);
}
```